# Why use the past simple tense in: "before I died"?

Tags: present-tense, simple-past, mood

It's *[The Simpsons Movie](https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/The_Simpsons_Movie/Transcript)*, again. Bart says this to Flanders right after he's entered the church Flanders was in.

> Bart: Listen, I was wondering if before I **died** I could pretend I had a father who cared for me.
>   Ned: Come here, son. There's always room for one more in the Flanders clan.

- Wouldn't it be okay if *died* was replaced with ***die***?
- Why should it be in the past tense?

Comment: I was wondering if this could be [the conditional tense](http://studyspanish.com/grammar/lessons/conditional/) poking its head into English.

Comment: What @Spencer said. I think it's like [But there was one thing, she said. If before he **went** he could manage to fix the horse trough,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22said+if+before+he+went+he+could%22) so it's more "conditional = hypothetical = **not present**" (as in *English only has two tenses - present and "not present"*).

Comment: @Spencer Oh, the conditional tense! I've been using it only with *wish* and *if*. Didn't know it's used this way. **edit** Well, it has *if*. I think I'm just ignorant.

Comment: Listen. I was just wondering if...
...before I died...
...I could pretend I had a father who...
...cared for me. This is the script from the movie. Are you sure about whether Bart uttered "died" or "die"? Don't forget there are many mistakes in a movie script and It's extremely difficult to tell between died and die.

Comment: @Rathony Yes, actually, I paused at this line and repeated the scene. And I really couldn't tell if it was *died* or *die*.

Comment: English tense is a real mystery and if you don't understand it, it is better to just move on. I would parse it as "I was wondering **if** I could pretend (that) I had a father who cared for me **before** I **die**, but without watching the movie, I can't tell you why and how it is used. Good luck.

Comment: Also, if the *if clause* is conditional, a comma would have made it clearer.as in "I was wondering if before I died, I could pretend I had a father who cared for me."

Comment: Ugh. Folks. Conditional is a **mood**, not a tense. There is no such thing as a conditional tense. Stop saying that. Please. It physically hurts.

Comment: @Rathony Saying that “English tense is a real mystery and if you don't understand it, it is better to just move on.” is a pretty silly thing to say on a site dedicated to linguists, etymologists, and serious English-language experts.

Comment: @tchrist Do you want me to quote more silly and foolish things that are going on on a site dedicated to linguists, etymologists, and serious English language experts? I can quote you more than thousand instances. Be careful with your comment. Using "pretty silly" doesn't seem to be in line with "be nice" policy.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: in some langauges, conditional is a tense. In English, hardly anything is a tense (in any sensible framework, there's no future tense, for example) and I'm not convinced that anything is a mood. I'd say conditional is a construction, or pattern.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no [tag:irrealis] tag, just [tag:irrealis-were], which I didn't think fitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the past tense form 'died' signifies that this is an *irrealis* (or *counter-factual*) condition, and therefore implies that he definitely hasn't got a father who cares for him.